# Double Variable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was randomly going through some Tough Integral Calculus Questions. Came across this question, which has two variables $x$ and $y$. I don't really have an approach for this question. Can someone please help with the solution. And if possible, please generalize these types of problems.
The Question goes like-
IF $x^2+y^2=2c^2(x^2-y^2)$ then

$$\int \frac{dx}{y(x^2+y^2+c^2)}=-\frac{1}{c^2}\ln\bigg(\frac{x^2+y^2}{g(x,y)}\bigg)$$

then

1. How do we find the relationship between $g(x,y)$ and $g(y,x)$,
2. How do we find the value of $g(x,x)$
3. To check whether $g(x,y)=0$ is a straight line?

Comment: Think about what $\int \dots\,dx$ means. How can you rewrite the given equation with no integral?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. The Question is exactly framed like this. I have made no particular changes

Comment: I'm telling you how to approach the problem. You need to think.

Comment: Oh sorry, Sir, I get what you're saying. It means the function is being integrated by dx. So all other variables would come out of the integral. Is this correct

Comment: No, because $y$ is implicitly (and pretty much explicitly) a function of $x$.

Comment: So do I have to proceed with converting these Cartesian coordinates into spherical coordinates?

Comment: No, no. Have you reread my very first comment?

Comment: I think by differentiating both sides I can get rid of the integral sign. But while doing that I faced yet another problem. That is differentiating with respect to what? Partial differentiation with respect to X?

Comment: Please format the mathematical symbols in your questions using MathJax.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Where did you see this question?